# Best way to install pygame on OS X Lion?

Tags: python, pygame

I tried to install pygame via pip but this fails.  Based on my google searches, it sounds like easy_install also fails.

I also checked out: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacLionCompile but the solution is incomplete.

I'm running python 2.7.1 bundled with Lion.

Suggestions?  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try the [binary package](http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip) for Lion, available on the [pygame website](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml).

It worked for me (OSX 10.7.1 with bundled Python 2.7.1)

Answer (score 8):

See the answer from this question: [PyGame in a virtualenv on OS X with brew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458911/pygame-in-a-virtualenv)

Essentially, the PyGame in PyPy hasn't been updated for a while.
The version in the repository has updated build scripts that handle Pythonbrew, virtualenv and other utilities.

The pip command to use is:

```
pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

Comment: You need to install mercurial either via apt-get, brew, etc, or via pip (its a python application).

Answer (score 7):

Just for the sake of anyone that googles this question, my lab has a wiki set up with instructions for installing Pygame with just about any configuration:

http://smash.psych.nyu.edu/labwiki/PyGameSetup

Answer (score 6):

I had good luck with macports:

1. Install macports if you don't already have it: http://www.macports.org/
2. Install python via macports: `sudo port install python26`. I typed in the command it said at the end to set it as my default python installation. If you don't, then in step 4 you'll have to run the app a different way.
3. Install pygame: `sudo port install py26-game`
4. Run your pygame app: `python main.py`

Comment: I second this approach. See my comment under http://stackoverflow.com/a/15707206/2596664 . (I'm popping my stack of answers in my browser and tying them together to pay it forward.)

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for this for myself and I stumbled upon this build that happens to work. I am using OSX 10.8.3 and python 2.7.

http://inside.catlin.edu/moodle/mod/resource/view.php?id=16736