# PyGame in a virtualenv on OS X with brew?

Tags: python, macos, pygame, virtualenv

Can't quite figure out how to install PyGame in a virtualenv on OSX Lion.  I'd really like to keep things contained in the virtualenv, if at all possible.

I've tried downloading the source for PyGame and running the included `setup.py` in the virtualenv, but it seems to be having a bunch of issues finding the SDL requirements even after installing those via Homebrew.

Any tips from someone that's set this up?

Comment: I've got it working and setup without any issues on Debian. I don't have or use OSX. What error messages are you seeing?

Comment: did you do https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/82/homebrew-on-leopard-fails-to-install#comment-627494

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, you can use it in [3 steps with brew](https://web.archive.org/web/20150621234806/https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/82/homebrew-on-leopard-fails-to-install#comment-627494):

```
brew install python
brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf smpeg portmidi 
/usr/local/share/python/pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

(this is how i did it, it's working perfectly.)

If you don't know [brew](https://brew.sh/), [start here](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew)

Comment: Interesting.  The above worked, although I used the virtualenv's pip instead of he one in /usr/local/share/python.  Not sure if that makes a difference or not.  I'm not clear as to why I need to use a separately hosted pygame though (i.e., http://bitbucket.org/pygame).  Shouldn't the "official" one work?  If not, why haven't the PyGame folks fixed this?

Comment: Probably because pygame requires other non python or pip-manageable libraries to be installed on the target machine - it is a bit more involved than a web lib - using sdl (an open source, cross platform equivalent of DirectX) for fast access to native framebuffers/card hardware or sound resources. The last step with the pip install using your virtual env's version is critical.

Comment: Please note: If you want to install PyGame to the virtualenv's `site-packages`, you'll have to setup the `virtualenv` using `--system-site-packages`. Then you can just use `pip install ...` instead of `/usr/local/share/python/pip install` and PyGame will be installed locally.

Comment: To get smpeg, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614518/homebrew-no-formula-for-smpeg)