# Homebrew: No formula for smpeg

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame, homebrew

I'm trying to install Pygame on my Mac OS 10.6.8 with Python3. I'm doing my best to follow the instructions here: http://florian-berger.de/en/articles/installing-pygame-for-python-3-on-os-x

And all seems well until this step:

```
brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf smpeg portmidi
```

Then it fails with "No available formula for smpeg". I get the same error if I try:

```
brew install smpeg
```

I've looked in /usr/local/Library/Formula and indeed, it is not there.

What's the smart way to move forward?
* Find, install and fix the old formula?
* Use an alternate way of installing smpeg?
* Having come this far with Homebrew, is there a smarter way to install Pygame?

I'd appreciate guidance on an approach to take and a link with help on how to get it down that that approach. I've kind of hit the limits of my sys admin skills.

Thanks!

NOTE: The instructions I've linked to (using straight up pip with no special path in front of it), plus the answer selected below and my comment, resulted in Pygame working in Python 2.7. I'm overjoyed. Sometime later I'll figure out how to make this work in Python3, but for now this is a pretty solid win.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`smpeg` has been moved to homebrew-headonly.  You can install it like this:

```
brew tap homebrew/headonly
brew install --HEAD smpeg
```

Comment: After this, I uninstalled and reinstalled pygame (using pip) so that the reinstall would include smpeg. You can test with two Python commands: import pygame, and pygame.image.get_extended(). If it returns 0, you don't have smpeg. After your tip, it returned 1. Thanks!

Comment: running `brew update` after the tapping helped me get through an error thrown during the installation

Answer (score 3):

**Update Jan 2016**

Installation on El Capitan (10.11.2) using Homebrew 0.9.5 (git revision 422e; last commit 2016-01-10) resulted in the following log

```
$ brew install smpeg
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/smpeg-0.4.5.el_capitan.bott
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring smpeg-0.4.5.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz   /usr/local/Cellar/smpeg/0.4.5: 22 files, 636.1K
```

which resulted in successful install of smpeg