# Is the wrong version of pygame being installed?

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I'm borrowing my friends mac and I've tried following instructions of installing python and pygame using homebrew and all that. Specifically following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0Cl4Crg7FE
And this post: http://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/2bsqe4/installing_python3_and_pygame_os_x_mavericks_and/

I've successfully managed to install python 3.4.1 and a version of pygame from https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame

So I now start to test my program to see if it works. But it doesn't because it says pygame has no `pygame.movie` module, which I am using to play a video.

I've done all of my programming on my windows7 computer using python 3.4.0 and pygame version 1.9.2a0, and it worked perfectly fine. Anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What's your `$PYTHONPATH` set to?

Comment: I don't know. I don't have access to his mac anymore and the next time I'll see it is on Wednesday. What is it I should look out for?

Comment: It needs to include the path of the python modules you have installed.

Comment: So how do I check this? What is the correct path? And if the path is wrong how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the README on [the github repo you linked](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame):

> You should definitely begin by installing a binary package for your system. **The binary packages usually come with or give the information needed for dependencies.** Choose an appropriate installer for your system and version of python from the pygame downloads page. http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

And that line that I bold-faced seems to be the root of your problem: You didn't install the dependencies, so you don't have video support, so when you built from source, it skipped `pygame.movie`.

Unfortunately, they only have binaries for Python 2.x, and only for older versions of OS X, which means you can't actually follow those instructions, and you're doing the right thing by building it manually.

I don't see where they list these dependencies on the download page. There's a link to Installation Notes, but it's a 404. And the README in the BitBucket repo doesn't list them either. (I'm not 100% sure BitBucket is the right place to look—the download page sends you to an svn repo, which sends you to the BitBucket repo, but the GitHub repo looks newer and just as official—but the GitHub repo has the same info…)

So… you may need to read through `config_darwin.py` and `config_unix.py`. But my first guess is that it's `SMPEG` or maybe `avformat` that you're missing, because `SMPEG` is how you display video in SDL, and `avformat` is how you convert video from other formats to something `SMPEG` can handle. So, if you don't have those, use Homebrew or the SDL.org binary installers or whatever you prefer to add them, then clean-rebuild PyGame.

Comment: But pygame versions provided from the website only support python2.x. I've already tried running my program using python2.7 and it's pygame compatible version, but of course it doesn't work because what I think is that there isn't a `pygame.movie` module in pygame for python2.7. This is just speculation. Are you telling me that I should download the latest provided and use the mac terminal to update it from the github repo?

Comment: @Nectok: OK, if you want to use Python 3.x and they don't have a binary (still? seriously? sigh…), then you were right to build it yourself. But that means you'll have to get all the optional dependencies yourself. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Right thanks. But first I want to make sure of one thing. I'm wondering if `pygame.movie` is the only problem here because it was the very first thing I tried to load before the other pygame modules. Is `pygame.movie` the only thing I'm missing from the old binaries to the newer 1.9.2a0 version? Because I also have a `pygame.music` in the program as well. Is `pygame.music` included in the old one? (bitbucket is the one that's the old one right?)

Comment: Just fire up an interactive interpreter and try to `import` each one that you're worried about, and that'll tell you what's missing.

Comment: I see. I do have some questions regarding your last paragraph though. Where and how would I be able to find `config_darwin.py` and `config_unix.py`, and what would it tell me? I've already converted my video into mpeg1 format so does that mean I won't need `avformat`? Specifically, how would I use Homebrew to install what I'm missing? Is there a list somewhere that tells me the commands for installing individual modules? Clean-rebuild = reinstall? Sorry about this, I'm not a mac person and this is the first program I've ever made.

Comment: @Nectok: Those files are in the top level directory of the source code you pulled from github, or can be viewed in the github web repo browser interface. Since they're pretty simple Python code, you should be able to get at least a reasonable idea of what they're searching for.

Comment: I've taken a look at the files but it just goes way over my head. I have no idea what I'm looking for and what I'd need to do with it. My ultimate goal is to use py2app to make a mac compatible standalone for my program, if saying this helps anything. (Maybe I can pass my files over and someone can export it for me. I'm kinda desperate :c )

Comment: @Nectok: If you're looking for someone to fix your project for you, rather than looking for an answer to a specific question, you're looking in the wrong place. Read the help; it explains what kinds of questions StackOverflow can and can't answer (and why), and what you're asking for is definitely in the "can't" column. If you're writing an open source project, maybe you can find some other way to attract contributors; if you're doing anything else, it sounds like you need to hire a programmer.

Comment: I seem to have successfully installed `smpeg`. I didn't know what you meant by clean-rebuild so I just reinstalled pygame after installing `smpeg` but when I tried to run my game again, it came up with the same error. `pygame.movie` could not be found, did I do something wrong? I installed `smpeg` following this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614518/homebrew-no-formula-for-smpeg

Comment: @Nectok: It's been a while since I built pygame, but I think it prints out a whole ton of information while it's configuring and building, and somewhere in there it should say something like: "pygame.movie: not building because ___".

Comment: I understood what you said a little after. I'm looking at the terminal and it says something like this. SMPEG: found 0.4.5, Framework smpeg not found, Framework CoreMIDI found, Framework Quicktime found. I've looked through the whole thing and `pygame.movie` doesn't even appear.

Comment: Is there maybe a way I can just grab `pygame.movie` module from somewhere and then place it inside the directories of the mac? Would that work?

Comment: I've figured from looking around that I need this `movie.so` file. Have any idea how I'm able to get that?

Comment: @Nectok: If you can find a build of `pygame.movie` somewhere, you can almost certainly find a build of the complete `pygame` package, so… just use that, don't try to use your existing `pygame` but copy over one module. Also, extension modules have to be built for the same Python you have—a package built for, say, Apple's pre-installed Python 2.7 is not going to work on your python.org or Homebrew Python 3.4.