# Pygame installation not working?

Tags: python, installation, osx-lion, pygame

I am trying to install pygame on my mac.
I'm using python 2.7 and have downloaded pygame for 2.7.
I do the normal install thing.
Then when I go on the shell and type `import pygame`
I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
        import pygame
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Ve… line 95, in <module>
        from pygame.base import *
    ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framew… 2): no suitable image found. Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/… no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

I'm using Lion by the way

Comment: What version did you install? Where did you get the package from? Did you use binary distribution?

Comment: You might also check answer to similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288571/best-way-to-install-pygame-on-os-x-lion

Comment: Shouldn't it go
import os, sys
from pygame import *

Answer (score 0):

Download the official Mac Python from Python.org. The Apple one that comes with the system does not work with pygame.