# Installing pygame using Macports

Tags: python, pygame, sublimetext2

I am installing pygame via macports. I followed the [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288571/best-way-to-install-pygame-on-os-x-lion) as such,

```
sudo port install py26-game
```

Wrote the pygame code as such:

```
#image settings
bif = "bg.jpg"
mif = "ball.jpg"

#Basic Settings for pygame
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

#Create a screen and load the images
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32) #size,flag,bit

background = pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
mouse_c = pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))

    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x -= mouse_c.get_width()/2
    y -= mouse_c.get_height()/2

    screen.blit(mouse_c,(x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

I am using sublime text 2 to build the game, but I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PygameTutorial.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pygame, sys
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

In my terminal, tried the same and have the same error:

```
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you're using the MacPorts version of Python, and not the built-in one. Assuming your MacPorts installation is in `/opt/local`, you'll need to do the following:

1. Edit your `~/.profile` and include this line at the very bottom:

   ```
   export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
   ```

   Restart your Terminal session, run `python` on the command line, and see if you can import pygame.
2. If that works, open a new file in Sublime with JSON syntax and paste in the following contents:

   ```json
   {
       "cmd": ["/opt/local/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
       "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
       "selector": "source.python"
   }
   ```

   Save the file in your `Packages/User` directory as `Python2.sublime-build` where `Packages` is the folder opened by selecting **`Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Browse Packages...`** - it should be `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages`. Then, when you want to build a Python project, select **`Tools -> Build System -> Python2`** and hit <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to build.

   Alternatively, if you want to use the **`Tools -> Build System -> Automatic`** setting, you can edit the original `Python.sublime-build` file. Open your `Packages` folder as above, go to the `Python` directory, and open `Python.sublime-build` in Sublime. Change the contents to those above (basically, just change `"cmd": ["python", ...` to `"cmd": ["/opt/local/bin/python", ...` and save. Please note that this only works with Sublime Text 2; if you're using ST3 you'll need to install [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to extract the `Python.sublime-build` file from the zipped `Python.sublime-package` file.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have pygame on the "site-packages" folder in the directory :

```
Python27/lib/site-packages
```

Sometimes that name of the file that contains it is different from "pygame", if you find something like `py26-game`

try changing the import to that name.

Comment: Nope. It's installed as `pygame`.